# Slim Framework call a slim function from another function in different php page

Tags: php, slim

How can I call a slim function from another function in different php page

Here My.php:

```
$app->get('/list/:id',function($id)
{
   //fill array here
   echo $somearray;
});

$app->post('/update/:id',function($id)
{
   //do update operation here

   //!Important : How can do this?
   echo $app->get('My.php/list/$id'); // call function above

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hello I have this in my production app.

Signature of route:

```
$app->get('xxx/:jobid', function ($jobid) use($app) {})->name('audit_edit');


//Get The Route you want... 
$route = $app->router()->getNamedRoute("audit_edit"); //returns Route
$route->setParams(array("jobid" => $audit->omc_id)); //Set the params

//Start a output buffer
ob_start();
$page2 = $route->dispatch(); //run the route
//Get the output
$page = ob_get_clean();
```

In my particular instance I need to capture the exact page and send it in an email. So by running the route and capturing the HTML i can simply send an html email with the captured page body. It works flawlessly.

Answer (score 5):

Even if i don't understand why you need to do this, try the following style (alternative in Slim to call functions)

```
$app->get('/list/:id', 'listById');
$app->post('/update/:id','updateById');

function listById($id)
{
   //fill array here
   echo $somearray;
});


function updateById($id){
   //do update operation here

   echo listById($id);

});
```

Comment: Because I do not have my functions in your way (define functions at  begining of the page) Let's say I wonder :)

Comment: But +1 for suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

New answer because it's a complete different solution (feel free to downvote the first ;-) ):

If you want to use anonymous functions, you can assign them to a variable and later call by variable.
because they're defined in the global context, they are not available until you give them to the other anonymous functions with `use` or `global`.

This is how it could be done with anonymus functions:

```
$app->get('/list/:id', ($list=function($id){
   //fill array here
   echo "executing func1... ";
   return 42;
}));
$app->get('/update/:id',function($id) use (&$list){
   echo "executing func2... ";
   echo $list(42);
});
$app->run();
```

This will output `execing func2... execing func1... 42`

Comment: great answer when have no any other option in slim :) but still I'm waiting for one to say "no you can't (or better)"

Comment: Ok, you're looking for a Slim-specific solution? Probably with [redirect()](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Route-Helpers) (nice, never seen this feature ;-) )

Comment: Great answer. I used this where I want to return updated json object after a PUT and it's a pita to construct the object, so I just exit via the corresponding get